# Kong: migrating plugin from 2.8.0 to 3.x

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin

I am migrating from Kong 2.8.0 to 3.0.0.
I have a few custom plugins which are giving me trouble while migrating.

Once i start migration I am getting this error:

```
[error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:560: error loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'file-log-extended': [postgres] 2 schema violations (fields: expected an array; name: field required for entity check)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:560: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

So, the problem to me seems related to the *schema.lua* :

```
local typedefs = require "kong.db.schema.typedefs"
local pl_utils = require "pl.utils"

return {
  fields = {
   path = { required = true, type = "string"},
   log_bodies = { type = "boolean", default = true }
  }
}
```

What I've done is changing the schema to:

```
...
return {
  fields = {{
    config = {
      type = "record",
      fields = { 
        path = { required = true, type = "string"},
        log_bodies = { type = "boolean", default = true }
      }
    }
  }}
}
```

But now when I start Kong I get the following error:

```
[error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:543: error 
loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'file-log-extended': failed converting legacy schema for file-log-extended: unknown legacy field attribute: "config"
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:543: in function 'init'
    init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

Can someone help me understand why I can't migrate properly this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the format was incorrect.
This version is accepted.

```
return {
  name="file-log-extended",
  fields = {
    {
      -- this plugin will only be applied to Services or Routes
      consumer = typedefs.no_consumer
    },
    {
      config = {
        type = "record",
        fields = { 
          -- Describe your plugin's configuration's schema here.        
          {
            path = { 
              required = true, 
              type = "string" 
            }
          },
          {
            log_bodies = { 
              type = "boolean", 
              default = true 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```